# Defining a two-variable function with a parity property

Tags: function-construction, replacement, pattern-matching, attributes

I would like to define a function that has the following property $f(-x,y)=f(x,-y)$.
An example is $f(x,y)=x y$. For simple inputs, I can impose this easily enough as:

```
f[-x, y] + f[x, -y] /. {f[-A_, B_] :> f[A, -B]}
(*2f[x, -y]*)
```

However when I want to examples with more complex arguments this does not work any longer, e.g.

```
f[-x + y, z] + f[x - y, -z] /. {f[-A_, B_] :> f[A, -B]}
(*f[x - y, -z] + f[-x + y, z]*)
```

How can I make the rule work in the second case?

In general, can I set the **Attributes** of the function so that this is done automatically?
I would eventually want to work with some longer expressions of type

```
f[x1 + x2 - x3, y] + f[x1 + x2 + x3, y] + f[-x1 - x2 + x3, -y] +  f[-x1 - x2 - x3, -y]/.rule
(* 2 f[x1 + x2 + x3, y] + 2 f[x1 + x2 - x3, y] *)
```

Comment: Upvalues perhaps?
f /: f[-x_, y_] := f[x, -y]

Comment: hm... it don't seem to work for the second example f[-x + y, z] + f[x - y, -z].

Comment: Right, I was think of using up values to look at patterns with a minus, f/:f[Minus[x_] + y_ + Minus[z_],  x + Minus[y_] +z]:=f[-x+y-z, etc, but didn’t try it yet. Just a suggestion of a direction to try

Comment: Perhaps a peak at FullForm[f[x-y+z,-x-y+z] might help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a general function that compares $f(a,b)$ with $f(-a,-b)$ and decides which one to prefer, for any choice of $(a,b)$. It's a matter of taste which form is more desired; here I use `Sort` (always picking the form that is higher in sorting order), which is unambiguous but may not be what you are looking for.

```
rule = f[a_, b_] :> Last[Sort[{f[a, b], f[-a, -b]}]];

f[-x, y] + f[x, -y] /. rule
(*    2 f[x, -y]    *)

f[-x + y, z] + f[x - y, -z] /. rule
(*    2 f[-x + y, z]    *)

f[x1 + x2 - x3, y] + f[x1 + x2 + x3, y] + f[-x1 - x2 + x3, -y] + f[-x1 - x2 - x3, -y] /. rule
(*    2 f[-x1 - x2 + x3, -y] + 2 f[x1 + x2 + x3, y]    *)
```

You may also need to use automatic simplifications to bring all terms into a common form, so that they can be combined:

```
f[-2 (x + y), z] + f[2 x + 2 y, -z] /. rule
(*    f[-2 x - 2 y, z] + f[-2 (x + y), z]    *)

rule2 = f[a_, b_] :> Last[Sort[FullSimplify[{f[a, b], f[-a, -b]}]]];

f[-2 (x + y), z] + f[2 x + 2 y, -z] /. rule2
(*    2 f[-2 (x + y), z]    *)
```